# Simple Form PHP $_POST not Working

Tags: php, xampp, localhost

```
/*loginform.php*/
<html lang="en">
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
<form method="post" action="login.php">
    <fieldset>
        <input name="email" type="text">
        <input name="password" type="text">
        <input type="submit">
    </fieldset>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Trying to run the above html code into the below file named "login.php" but it is not pulling any POST data from the form, I have no reason why. I feel like its PhpStorm and XAMPP conflicting, but they are in the right file path ~/xampp/htdocs/folder and the php.exe is from ~/xampp/php/php.exe and it is recognized by PhpStorm.

I realize I should be using isset(), but I'm just trying to figure out what is the real issue.

```
/*login.php*/
<?php
echo $_POST['email'];
echo $_POST['password']; 
?>
```

### Output:

Notice: Undefined index: email in 
C:\Users\danie\Desktop\xampp\htdocs\gclol\login.php on line 2

Notice: Undefined index: email in 
C:\Users\danie\Desktop\xampp\htdocs\gclol\login.php on line 3

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: try to `print_r($_POST)`  in login.php

Comment: Gives me a blank array "Array()". I've also tried var_dump(). Also a blank array.

Comment: try $_REQUEST global variable

Comment: @uzaif I did, no luck. @ Iuʇǝƃɹɐʇoɹ Yes. I am filling it out and clicking the submit button.

Comment: @DanielDingess i try your code in my machine and it work fine no error is shown to me i am using xampp

Comment: I was pretty certain it would run on another machine. Although this is a newly wiped computer, and I don't know what could be wrong with the file system. I'm gonna try re-installing XAMPP now.

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue:

Intellij was going to this by default: http://localhost:63342/gclol/login.php

When it needed to go to my localhost hosted at my MAMP port here: http://localhost/gclol/login.php

Guess, I shouldn't use IDE's in Linux anyways. Back to the good ol' text editors. Lesson learned.

Comment: For those who find this later: PHPStorm is a spectacular product, and has increased my code quality by > 50% or more, and my speed of development / troubleshooting by double or more.  The issue is not in using PHPStorm, it's in understanding how thing are configured / interact, and working _with_ that.

Answer (score 0):

URL tells that you are using PhpStorm's (or other IDE's) built in web server.

If you want to use your proper web server (e.g. Apache) then please create and configure Deployment entry and mark it as Default for this project -- if no deployment specified (that's where IDE takes base URL from) PhpStorm will use built-in web server.

That's the way I solved my trouble.