# Simple PHP form issue

Tags: php, html

I'm trying to create a simple form using the code from the w3schools PHP tutorial but I'm not getting the intended result, an echo of the contents of my name and email input elements.

The PHP loads with all the HTML intact and working but without the information from my form elements.

Example:

[image]

My result:

[image]

HTML code:

```
<html>
<body>

    <form action="welcome.php" method="GET">
    Name: <input type="text" name="name"><br>
    E-mail: <input type="text" name="email"><br>
    <input type="submit">
    </form>

</body>
</html>
```

PHP:

```
<html>
<body>

Welcome <?php echo $_GET["name"]; ?><br>
Your email address is: <?php echo $_GET["email"]; ?>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Are you sure you have webserver installed?

Comment: I have XAMPP installed with Apache turned on.

Comment: Do you fill out the inputs and submit the form? Or Directly call the link?

Comment: Yes, I type something in the input forms and click the submit button. It redirects me to my php page with the output from my screenshot above.

Comment: Your code has no error. Just one thing, what is the name of PHP file that you set?

Comment: The name of my PHP file is welcome.php

Comment: Try going to the following link (Change 127.0.0.1 to your subdomain if you're using Apache vHosts) - Just want to see if it'll actually add the data in or not

127.0.0.1?name=myname?email=myemail@domain.com

Comment: Takes me to my XAMPP dashboard.

Comment: @DarrenO'BRIEN, Josh meant "127.0.0.1/welcome.php?name=myname&email=myemail@domain.com".

Comment: That seems to work. Both name and email are showing up.

Comment: @DarrenO'BRIEN, are the HTML form and the PHP script in the same directory?

Comment: Yes, they're both in htdocs in my XAMPP folder.

Comment: create a script named `test.php` and add `<?php echo "php is installed";?>`, what do you see when you run it?

Comment: When you ckick submit button, are name and email passing through  url

Comment: @DarrenO'BRIEN, would you be so kind as to substitute `action="welcome.php"` with `action="./welcome.php"` and see if that works? Also please include a [`DOCTYPE` declaration](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/HTML5/Introduction_to_HTML5) in both documents and make sure the permissions on the directory are properly set.

Comment: I put your files into my webserver, you can run it https://emojionline.org/test/ Everything works normally. You try to remove your webserver and reinstall it again in full mode (if windows, run as administrator).

Comment: @DarrenO'BRIEN, it could also be an IDE [getting in the way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36879471/simple-form-php-post-not-working).

Comment: Okay, I removed my webserver and reinstalled and it seems to work fine when I type localhost/register.html in the browser.

Comment: That means solved?

Comment: I believe so. I think there may just have been something wrong with my webserver.

Comment: Don't forget upvote for me :)

Comment: @DarrenO'BRIEN, that's good to hear. Good luck and don't trust everything w3fools say :)

Answer (score 0):

It's simple as that:

```
<?php
$name = $_GET['name'];
$email = $_GET['email'];

if (isset($_GET['submit'])) {
    echo "Welcome " . $name . "<br>";
    echo "Your email is " . $email;
}
?>
<html>
<body>
<form>
    Name: <input type="text" name="name"><br>
    E-mail: <input type="text" name="email"><br>
    <input type="submit" name="submit">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

The default method of the form is **$_GET** and the action is the current php file, so its not mandatory to write'em. Try this example and i'll help if the problem is still not solved

Comment: `$_GET` is not a method - it's a [superglobal](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.superglobals.php). I am not sure his script is getting the variables transferred over to it, so he's most likely having server setup issues.